# Canvas gradient performance

Tags: html, performance, canvas, gradient, fog

I am currently programming a little game using canvas. For the game I need some kind of fog which hides the most part of the map and only a small area around the player should be visible. Therfor I use a second canvas to overlay the one where the game takes place and fill it with a gradient (from transparent to black):

```
function drawFog(){
fogc.clearRect(0,0,700,600);
// Create gradient
var grd=fogc.createRadialGradient(player.getPosX(),player.getPosY(),0,player.getPosX(),player.getPosY(),100);
grd.addColorStop(0,"rgba(50,50,50,0)");
grd.addColorStop(1,"black");

// Fill with gradient
fogc.fillStyle=grd;
fogc.fillRect(0,0,700,600);
}
```

Unfortunatly this is causing huge perfomance problems since it will be redrawn for every frame.

I wanted to ask if there might be a better solution to achieve the same effect with a better performance.

Comment: Would it help if you only fill the 200x200 area with gradient? You can fill the whole canvas with black (or just refill the previous gradient part in black), erase the gradient part, then draw the gradient upon.

Comment: Actually I just tried that and it has no effect at all, I think the problem is the gradient itself.

Comment: How about using an additional invisible 200x200 canvas to "cache" the gradient? You can just `drawImage` then, which I think should be faster.

Comment: Well that kinda works. The performance is not nearly as good as without the fog (Firefox uses 20% CPU with fog instead of 5% CPU without it) but the animation now is fluid. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cache the gradient to an off-screen canvas then draw in the canvas with drawImage() instead:

- Create an off-screen canvas the size of the fog
- Draw in the gradient
- Use off-screen canvas as an image when you need the fog.

This way the processing creating and calculating the gradient is eliminated. Drawing an image is basically a copy operation (there is a little bit more, but performance is very good).

```
function createFog(player) {

    // Create off-screen canvas and gradient
    var fogCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = fogCanvas.getContext('2d'),
        grd = fogc.createRadialGradient(player.getPosX(),
                                        player.getPosY(),
                                        0,player.getPosX(),
                                        player.getPosY(),100);

    fogCanvas.width = 700;
    fogCanvas.height = 700;

    grd.addColorStop(0,"rgba(50,50,50,0)");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"black");

    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,700,600);

    return fogCanvas;
}
```

Now you can simply draw in the canvas returned from the above function instead of creating the gradient every time:

```
var fog = createFog(player);
ctx.drawImage(fog, x, y);
```