# Canvas animation does not appear to be running at 60 fps

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, css-animations

I'm trying to emulate how smooth this website is: http://material.cmiscm.com/ (You may have seen it before)

So, I'm starting very very small and simply trying to emulate the way the gradient in the purple section fades from the box. His gradient is diagonal -- for simplicity, mine is horizontal.

*But*, my problem is my gradient comes in very choppily, even when I try changing the value of `RECT_INCREMENT`

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/16he6jfu/

**Raw code (ctrl +v'able)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
    #canvas {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: #6D00D0;
    }
</style>
<body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="555">

        </canvas>
</body>
<script>

var MAX_RECT_LENGTH = 800;
var RECT_INCREMENT = 50;
var RECT_X_ORIG = 0;
var RECT_Y_ORIG = 100;
var RECT_Y_MIN = 0;
var RECT_Y_MAX = 100;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var gra = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 800, 0);
gra.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(229, 88, 95, .6)');
gra.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');

var path = 0;
function draw(){

    if (path < MAX_RECT_LENGTH) {
        context.beginPath();
        // 1
        context.moveTo(RECT_X_ORIG + path, RECT_Y_ORIG);    
        //console.log('1) ' + (RECT_X_ORIG + path) + ', ' + RECT_Y_ORIG);
        // 2
        path = path+RECT_INCREMENT;
        context.lineTo(RECT_X_ORIG + path, RECT_Y_ORIG);    
        //console.log('2) ' + (RECT_X_ORIG + path) + ', ' + RECT_Y_ORIG);
        // 3
        context.lineTo(RECT_X_ORIG + path, RECT_Y_MIN);     
        //console.log('3) ' + (RECT_X_ORIG + path) + ', ' + RECT_Y_MIN);
        // 4
        context.lineTo(RECT_X_ORIG + path - RECT_INCREMENT, RECT_Y_MIN);                                
        //console.log('4) ' + (RECT_X_ORIG + path - RECT_INCREMENT) + ', ' + RECT_Y_MIN);
        // 5
        context.lineTo(RECT_X_ORIG + path - RECT_INCREMENT, RECT_Y_MAX);                                
        //console.log('5) ' + (RECT_X_ORIG + path - RECT_INCREMENT) + ', ' + RECT_Y_MAX);

        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle=gra;
        context.fill();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


window.onload = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine on my machine.

Comment: Mine too. Maybe your machine is taxed or crap.

Comment: Crazy! My machine IS crap, yet doesn't lag on the website I linked, but does on mine. This may be difficult for me to troubleshoot. Thanks guys!

Comment: Tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877240/canvas-gradient-performance/21891617#21891617

Comment: Awesome link @K3N, thanks. Looks like Creating or Filling things once, then Drawing them piece-by-piece, is a good general tactic? Or is that an inaccurate interpretation?

Comment: @HC_ sounds about right to me - it's generally faster to copy bitmap to bitmap instead of rasterizing, and you can do a portion from that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradients are somewhat expensive to create. Instead of recreating a gradient on every animation loop, just create the full gradient rect at the start of your app and incrementally display it in the loop.

**Here's example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var rect=createRectCanvas();
var width=1;

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.drawImage(rect,0,0,width,rect.height,0,0,width,rect.height);
    width+=10;
    if(width<cw && width<rect.width){
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}

function createRectCanvas(){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var context=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=800;
    c.height=100;
    var gra = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 800, 0);
    gra.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(229, 88, 95, .6)');
    gra.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
    context.fillStyle=gra;
    context.fillRect(0,0,800,100);
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=900 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such a thorough answer! I really originally wanted to ask if I was doing something especially inefficient but.. wasn't sure if it was a dumb question. I had one alternate solution I was attempting, if you don't mind me running it by you. I was going to create the gradient, and create a covering rect on top of it (that matches the background color), and then translating said rect "off" of the gradient rect. Main problem is, I currently end up translating the entire canvas. Is this solution worth pursuing/possible on a single canvas?

Comment: @HC_. That sounds OK -- kind of like opening the top of a sliding-top box. You will have to redraw the gradient "background" and then increase the `x` value of the revealing rectangle. But, IMHO, using the clipping version of `drawImage` (as in my example) seems easier since there are less moving-parts. Good luck with your project!