# Why aren't I getting performance improvements with my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make a simple maze navigation game using an HTML5 canvas, where the player character stays in the center of the screen and the maze moves around them.

The maze is represented using a 2D array of tile objects, so my first approach to drawing was something like:

```
for(var row=frameStart; row<=frameEnd; row++) {
    for(var col=frameStart; col<=frameEnd; col++)
        maze[row][col].draw();
    }
}
```

...where frameStart and frameEnd are computed each call to the paint method in order to avoid drawing parts of the maze that aren't visible. Anyway, this was a bit too slow for me, so I decided to save the whole maze into an image using

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

So now, I'm drawing the maze just one time, saving it into an image, and from then on just drawing a part of that saved image every frame using `ctx.drawImage(img, ...)` instead of looping through lots of tile elements and drawing each individually.

However, I found that this method is not noticeably faster, and I'm at a loss for how I can increase the performance any further, and am left wondering why my image idea didn't increase the performance. It currently takes longer than I'd like to render each frame. I currently have the game locked into rendering every single frame so I can easily see how long it takes to do so based on how fast the player character moves.

Comment: The code you've shown should have had some efficiency improvement. I suspect there are other things going on which prevent your game from actually appearing faster. Can you provide a link to the game?

Comment: Edge doesn't want to start the maze at all. Chrome seems to work fine, getting <10ms per frame. Firefox has this slow render problem, getting around 100ms per frame, ~10fps. Removing the lighting gradient speeds things up quite a bit. [An answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21891617/367865) suggests caching the gradient as an image (similar to what you're doing with the maze) and then drawing those. You could set up an algorithm to generate 10-15 of these and pick randomly between them to get the flickering effect. You might also consider just rendering as layered HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Improve rendering

Looking at your game I found it ran just fine on my machine.

**Use requestAnimationFrame**

But looking at your code you have implemented the rendering in a bad way.

You are placing renders back to back with

```
    ... cut from bottom of function reactToUserInput
    if(needsRedraw) {
        // Redraw canvas with interpolation
        drawMaze(true, oldLocation, 0);
        return; // drawMaze will call this function when it's done
    }
}

drawMaze();
setTimeout(reactToUserInput, 0);
```

in function `reactToUserInput`

And in `drawMaze()`

```
// Either continue interpolation, recall user input function, or stop entirely
if (interpolate) {
    if (interpOffset.mag == 0) {
        reactToUserInput();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            drawMaze(true, oldUserLocation, recurseCount + 1);
        }, 0);
    }
    return;
}
```

This can for some hardware setups cause you avoidable slowdowns.

Use `requestAnimationFrame` to render the frame every 1/60th second. This will also throttle your game on fast machines as i can not see any time controlled movement. It will also help the rendering on machines with low GPU RAM and GPU power better manage the GPU state as now you are forcing state changes when not needed.

Any rendering done at over 60fps just will not be seen by the user, so avoid needless rendering.

**Why is preRendering not helping**

Then I ran a profile on your game and the results show that indeed the drawCell function is the bottleneck. The call to `ctx.drawImage` in `drawCell` accounts for 32% of your overall processing. (but this value is misleading as you are constantly rendering)

The reason your rendering is not improved by prerendering is that you are asking too much of the GPU. The maze as I saw it is 150 tiles by 150 tiles with each cell being 65 by 65 pixels. That makes the dimension of the whole maze 9750 by 9750 pixels  consuming a total of 380.25MB of GPU memory that you are sharing with the page, the OS and any other process that is happening. Only the very top end machines will be happy to handle that amount of RAM, but the rest will be frantically paging it from system RAM causing the slowdown (compounded by the constant rendering).

Rule of thumb about images sizes on the canvas. Never try to use images greater than 4 times the longest resolution of the device. Devices are tuned to the resolution of the display and will happily deal with images that are near that resolution. Go over that and you exceed the capabilities of the hardware.

**How to fix and get a good frame rate.**

Looking at the game there is no reason why it should not be running at 60fps on all devices.

Use requestAnimationFrame to time the rendering and user input (nobody can toggle a key at over 60hz and your game does not demand instant reaction).

Reduce pixel memory usage. Your tiles are 65 by 65 which means that in the gpu the till image occupies 128 by 128 pixels in memory. Search "rendering powers of two" to find out why.

Change the cell resolution to 64 by 64.

Rather than pre render the whole scene create a offscreen canvas that is the play area size plus 2 cells. So if the number of cells to draw is 32 by 32 then create a canvas that is 34 by 34 cells. On first render draw all the 34 by 34 cells to that canvas. Then draw that canvas to follow the player, when the play get to a point and there are no cells along the edge that you are moving to, copy the canvas onto itself to make room for new cells in the direction of travel, then render the row or column  of missing cells.

```
// playfield is the offscreen canvas with .ctx as it context
playfield.ctx = playfield.getContext("2d");

// to move one cell up in the playfield

playfield.ctx.drawImage(playfield,
      0, cellSize, playfield.width, playfield.height-cellSize,
      0,0,playfield.width, playfield.height-cellSize
)

// then draw the missing bottom row of cells only

// then just draw the playfield to the onscreen canvas 
ctx.drawImage(playfield, mazeLeft, mazeTop)
```

It will take a bit of a rewrite but will get your game running very smoothly and get you back to concentrating on game play rather than performance.

Comment: Nice answer! Concise, explanatory & useful. :-)